# Non Parametric Multi-Group Non-Inferiority Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, non-inferiority

I have an experiment with 3 conditions.  I am interested in showing evidence that the mean of one group is no worse than another.  I believe this is called a multi-group non-inferior test.  My data is not normally distributed.  Can someone suggest what statistical test is appropriate for this? Also what any packages that use those would be great, I usually use python for my statistical tests.  Thank  you for any help!

Comment: Wowza... that's arcane! Wellek gives a pretty succinct derivation and example of "A nonparametric $k$-sample test for equivalence" in 7.5 of his 2010 text. It is not equivalence, by you might be able to work out a noninferiority adaptation of the test.

Comment: @Alexis thanks is there a good test/stat package for non parametric non inferior test for two samples?

Comment: Well, Wellek gives code (R I think, maybe SAS or Python also?) for all examples in his book. For TOST style tests, I have published the [tost](https://alexisdinno.com/Software/index.shtml#tost) package.

Comment: @Alexis thanks but TOST tests assume normal distribution right?

Comment: Well, unless you have a tiny sample rank sum tests and sign rank tests (and sign tests for that matter), make due with a $z$ test, because there are transformations of the nonparametric statistic into an approximately standard normal distribution.